# Fb button not aligned with twitter and g+ button

Tags: html, css

For some reason "Like" button is not aligned with g+ and twitter button on my page. (See image below to see what I mean )

[image]

I didn't change any styles. I just add those 3 button on my page. Here is the code for all 3 buttons:

```
            <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="url" data-count="none">Tweet</a>

           <div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="none"></div>



            <div class="fb-like" data-href="url" data-layout="button" 
                data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
```

All 3. buttons are in one div with width 300px.

Any ideas how to align the fb button with g+ and  tweeter button horizontally?

EDIT:

DIV that holds three buttons CSS

```
#fan {

   width: 300px;
    background-color:#9b9b9b;
    border-radius:6px;
    padding: 4px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;



}
```

Comment: if we can't see the css's or a fiddle it's quite difficult to know what the problem is. maybe you can fix it with vertical-align but...

Comment: The problem with the like button is, that your original HTML is not what you see as FB itself (radically) changes the HTML. g+1 also does it